# Issue with model registry Azure - onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NoSuchFile: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 3 : NO_SUCHFILE

Tags: python, azure, deployment, model, registry

I am trying to load an onnx model from azure registry but it is unable to locate the mode. The error i am getting is as follows -

ERROR

> 2021-12-01 11:06:44,182 | root | ERROR | Encountered Exception
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/aml_blueprint.py",
> line 201, in register
> main.init()   File "/var/azureml-app/211201115339-240776055/score.py", line 11, in init
> session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model)   File "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py",
> line 206, in **init**
> self._create_inference_session(providers, provider_options)   File "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py",
> line 226, in _create_inference_session
> sess = C.InferenceSession(session_options, self._model_path, True, self._read_config_from_model)
> onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NoSuchFile:
> [ONNXRuntimeError] : 3 : NO_SUCHFILE : Load model from mnist.onnx
> failed:Load model mnist.onnx failed. File doesn't exist

My INIT FUNCTION is as follows in score.py

```
def init():
    global session
    model = "mnist.onnx"
    session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model)
```

Model in registry looks like that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the path is as follows - "/var/azureml-app/azureml-models/mnist/1/mnist.onnx"